# How to destroy Shiny observers for specific users

Tags: r, shiny

How do I remove observers for only specific users?

I have a group of individuals who all interact in a session at the same time. Occasionaly I have to trigger events for all them simulataneously. I only use one person to trigger a global reactiveValue, and when observed some calculations are performed.

### server.R

```
## only execute code if user is user1
o <- observeEvent( GlobalTriggers$Update, {    
    if( GlobalTriggers$Update & (userPID==1)) {
        ## Do some updating
    }
})
```

I would like to stop other users from doing that observing. I have tried adding the following

### server_addition.R

```
## Initial Observer
o_1 <- observeEvent(Triggers$Submit, {
        cat("Submit \n")

        ## Future Observers
        if (userPID !=1 ){
            cat("Destroy \n")
            o$destroy()
            o_1$destroy()
        }

})
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful for you?

Comment: Somewhat. It seems very similar to my original approach, which I have now included in the question. Could you please elaborate on what the second two observers are doing

Comment: Its different in the way that you can differentiate between global and user specific reactive values and et therefore the sessions "communicate" with each other,...see my edit.

Comment: Why is it more desireable to add local reactives that update based on a global trigger? I can just condition the global reactive to execute code only `if userPID==1` without those extra observers. Why is your code better than just my `server.R`?